How to upload property files stored in gitlab to physical datacenters using harness next0gen
I have property files saved in gitlab specific for every region and env, ex: app.prop_INDIA-DEV, app.prop_INDIA-QA...
Now I am trying to upload these files into their respective server using Harness next-gen, How to do it?
I have gone through harness documentation but didn't get any straight answer. I am not able to understand how can I fetch the specific file and deploy in to respective server
